# iphone: a way to optimize image loading on scrollview.

Tags: iphone, image, scrollview

In my app, I display images with scrollview. I avoid memory issue by adding view as user scroll through. Scrolling seems fine but it stop in split second when new image is loaded on next/pervious view. I tried to load image on NSThread but no performance was improved.

I use `[UIImage imageWithData:]` to load image. I wonder if there is a way to load an image more efficient way. It would be appreciated for any comments regard this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to keep three pictures at once in memory: the picture on the current screen, the picture on the next screen and the picture on the previous screen. By doing this you can scroll smoothly. You can use your `imageWithData` method with this procedure.

It gets even simpler if you use `imageNamed` instead, because this method caches the pictures if it has enough memory. So you just have to load the current picture and the next picture by just calling

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"nextPic"];
```

By executing this, it loads the picture into the cache but does not display it. The next time you have to display the picture it is already in memory.

Comment: And I think you could execute the nextPic Loading on a background thread,too.

Comment: I keep 3 pictures, problem is there's overhead when loading new picture. I tried to execute on background either, but didn't help

Comment: how big is the picture? is it much larger than the screen?

Comment: each approximately 150-200k, and sizes are vary but around 1100 x 1100

Comment: How large is your picture? Why is it that large? do you want to zoom into it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3462/discussion-between-gorillapatch-and-realfree)

Comment: Well `imageNamed` had a memory leak issue in iOS 3.0. Now it should work fine. Using it will lead to more memory consumption which should go down when a memory warning comes in. Check that with leaks and the simulator. Another approach would be to use a smaller image and a CATiledLayer-backed scroll view which dynamically loads the right resolution like it is done in the maps app in iOS.